Batch class issue

I have custom objects Review__c, Order__c.

Order__c is parent of Review__c and Case.
Review__c is a parent of Case.



There are fields on Review__c named as:

Rating__c (number(2,2),
POSAccount__c (lookup Account),
Order__c (lookup Order__c).

I want to fetch and delete the the duplicates per Order__c based on below criteria:
If the POSAccount__c for a Review__c is equal to '0013J00000TkTZCQA3' then check the Rating__c of the review
1. If the rating is less than 4 keep only the those reviews who has case assigned to them, delete rest.
2. If the rating is >=4 then keep the first Review__c per order and delete other
If the POSAccount__c for a Review__c is equal to '001Ei000007yoZ3IAI' OR '001Ei000007yrTtIAI' then
1. Keep the first review per order and delete the other
Make sure that the duplication should be based on Order__c. If the Order__c field on Review__c is blank then it should not fetch those records.
This is my code currently. The code is correct considering all the requirement for deleting the duplicate records, but there is an issue. The start query return more than 50000 records and sends the same to execute method. Now the execute method runs in batches of 2000, hence it find the duplicates from that 2000 records only, in each chunk. Hence all the duplicates from the 50000 are not deleted. Can someone please help.
    global class SchDeleteReviews implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{   
    private static ReviewBatchDeletion__c settings = ReviewBatchDeletion__c.getOrgDefaults();
    
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(new SchDeleteReviews(), 2000);
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        Id tlPOSAccountId = settings.TbPOSAccount__c;
        Id hStationPOSAccount1Id = settings.HSPOSAccount1__c;
        Id hStationPOSAccount2Id = settings.HSPOSAccount2__c;
        
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Rating__c, POSAccount__c, Order__c FROM Review__c WHERE Order__c != NULL 
                                         AND (POSAccount__c =: tlPOSAccountId OR POSAccount__c =: hStationPOSAccount1Id OR 
                                         POSAccount__c =: hStationPOSAccount2Id) AND CreatedDate = THIS_MONTH]);
    } 
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> records)
    {           
        Id tlPOSAccountId = settings.TbPOSAccount__c;
        Id hStationPOSAccount1Id = settings.HSPOSAccount1__c;
        Id hStationPOSAccount2Id = settings.HSPOSAccount2__c;
        
        List<Review__c> reviews = (List<Review__c>)records;
        Set<Id> OrderIds = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id, List<Review__c>> OrderToReviews = new Map<Id, List<Review__c>>();
        
        for (Review__c review : reviews) {
            if (!OrderToReviews.containsKey(review.Order__c)) {
                OrderToReviews.put(review.Order__c, new List<Review__c>());
            }
            OrderToReviews.get(review.Order__c).add(review);
            OrderIds.add(review.Order__c);
        }
        
        Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case>();
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Review__c FROM Case WHERE Review__c IN :reviews];
        for (Case c : cases) {
            caseMap.put(c.Review__c, c);
        }
        
        List<Review__c> toDelete = new List<Review__c>();
        
        for (Id OrderId : OrderToReviews.keySet()) {
            List<Review__c> reviewsForOrder = OrderToReviews.get(OrderId);
            if (reviewsForOrder.size() <= 1) {
                continue;
            }
            
            Id posAccountId = reviewsForOrder[0].POSAccount__c;
            if (posAccountId == tlPOSAccountId) {
                List<Review__c> lowRatedReviews = new List<Review__c>();
                List<Review__c> highRatedReviews = new List<Review__c>();
                
                for (Review__c review : reviewsForOrder) {
                    if (review.Rating__c < 4) {
                        lowRatedReviews.add(review);
                    } else {
                        highRatedReviews.add(review);
                    }
                }
                
                if (!highRatedReviews.isEmpty()) {
                    Review__c reviewToKeep = highRatedReviews[0];
                    for (Integer i = 1; i < highRatedReviews.size(); i++) {
                        toDelete.add(highRatedReviews[i]);
                    }
                }
                
                if (!lowRatedReviews.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Review__c review : lowRatedReviews) {
                        if (!caseMap.containsKey(review.Id)) {
                            toDelete.add(review);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (posAccountId == hStationPOSAccount1Id || posAccountId == hStationPOSAccount2Id) {
                Review__c reviewToKeep = reviewsForOrder[0];
                for (Integer i = 1; i < reviewsForOrder.size(); i++) {
                    toDelete.add(reviewsForOrder[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (!toDelete.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Database.delete(toDelete, false);
                //Database.emptyRecycleBin(toDelete);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error during delete operation: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
    {                  
        //System.debug('Batch processing completed.');
    }
}


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You'll be better off 1) building processes to prevent duplicate creation, and 2) buying a 3rd party app that can find and merge/delete remaining duplicates.

Try ordering by your deduping criteria.  At least the Order__c.  But that could still fail if you happen to cross a 2000 record boundery.  Say the last record in a batch has a value of XYZZY and the first in the next batch has the same and meets the criteria.
You might be able to work around that by making the class stateful and then put the data from the last batch in a class variable so it's available in the next batch.
